# Filter ArrayObject (PHP)

Tags: php, array-filter, arrayobject

I have my data in **`ArrayObject`**, simply representing an array. I need to **filter** the data, function **`array_filter()`** would work great. However, it **does not work** with `ArrayObject` as argument. What's the best way to treat with this? Is there any standard function which handles filtering for me?

Example:

```
$my_data = ArrayObject(array(1,2,3));
$result = array_object_filter($my_data, function($item) { return $item !== 2; });
```

Is there any `array_object_filter` function?

Comment: Can't you use a foreach loop?

Comment: Yes, I can. But it seems a bit ugly to me. I know several approaches to solve this problem, but I'd like to hear the best one. None of what I know is really clean.

Comment: What do you mean by "clean"? Don't you think that array_filter() uses a loop internally?

Comment: Yes, internally. That's what I consider clean, standard library function.

Comment: There simply isn't a pre-built PHP function to do what you are asking for. See the function list at http://php.net/arrayobject - that's all there is. PHP will never do everything for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about you export it to an actual array, and then create a new Array Object?

```
$my_data = new ArrayObject(array(1,2,3));
$result = new ArrayObject( 
    array_filter( (array) $my_data, function($item) { 
         return $item !== 2; 
    })
);
```

Comment: I did this, but it seems ugly for me. Is there anything prettier? Since it is object, I can extend it and add the filter method to it... But really nothing in standard library?

Comment: @PavelS. Not that I know of, anyway. Obviously, you could indeed extend ArrayObject to a FilterableArrayObject which takes an anonymous function and takes care of the filtering. This probably is the "cleanest" solution, although I'd argue that when you're filtering, you'd end up with a different instance of the ArrayObject anyway, so this solution seems optimal.

Answer (score 2):

How about subclassing the ArrayObject and adding a new method to it:

```
/**
 * Filters elements using a callback function.
 *
 * @param callable $callback The callback function to use
 *
 * @return self
 */
public function filter(/* callable */ $callback = null)
{
    $this->exchangeArray(array_filter($this->getArrayCopy(), $callback));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: nice! exactly what I was going to do, if didn't find this one

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$my_data = new ArrayObject(array(1,2,3));
$callback = function($item) { return $item !== 2; };
$result = new ArrayObject;
foreach ($my_data as $k => $item) if ($callback($item)) $result[$k] = $item;
```

Alternately, you can define an array_object_filter() function yourself:

```
function array_object_filter($array, $callback) {
    $result = new ArrayObject;
    foreach ($array as $k => $item) if ($callback($item)) $result[$k] = $item;
    return $result;
}
```